# Stopping the default Operating System from Booting

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows-10

I use Linux 16.04 and Windows 10 in Dual Boot mode. I have Grub customizer installed and reordered my boot list. But I want to stop the default operating system to boot after the initial 10 seconds passed. I want it to halt as long as I do not choose any operating system to boot. I am badly in need of this. But do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/395373/how-do-i-prevent-grub2-from-automatically-booting-into-an-os), you need to set `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to -1 in `/etc/default/grub` file and execute `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: When the Grub menu appears just press the spacebar within the 10 secs.

Comment: @PaulBenson That would still require user interaction on each boot.